# Generate PKCS12 file using Java

Tags: java, jce, pkcs#12

I need to generate a PKCS12 file using Java.
Actually, I need to automate the following certificate generation using openssl (the ca was created previously and is not pretended to automate its creation):

> openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
>
> openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
>
> openssl ca -keyfile ca.key -cert ca.crt -out client.crt -policy policy_anything -infiles client.csr
>
> openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12 -name client

I want to know if it's possible to perform this without using Bouncycastle or similar libraries, just only JCE, because I didn't find any info related with the PKCS12 generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with creation keypairs and certificates but JCE has no API for signing (this is absolutely, I've spent lots of time searching it). Bouncycatle lib is a right choice.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a PKCS#12 is easy - that can be done by writing [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) "PKCS12" instance, add the certificate and keys and then save it to a file using the store(...) method.

The rest is a bit more problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Robert, the problem is that i don't use a Keystore. I just create this pkcs certificate as a result of a registration in a web, to control to the new user created the access to other URL. So, i need to reproduce the commented openssl commands, that creates just a pkcs, without a keystore.

Comment: From Java perspective a PKCS#12 file is a KeyStore. Java contains a number of KeyStore implementations like PKCS#12 and JKS. Both are accessed exactly the same way - just use `java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");`